# Expanding variable scope beyond curly braces in Java

Tags: java, scope, curly-braces

Let's say I have the following code block:

```
int    version;
String content;
synchronized (foo) {
    version = foo.getVersion();
    content = foo.getContent();
}
// Do something with version and content
```

Its purpose is to grab a thread-safe consistent view of the version and content of some object foo.

Is there a way to write it more concisely to look more like this?

```
synchronized (foo) {
    int    version = foo.getVersion();
    String content = foo.getContent();
}
// Do something with version and content
```

The problem is that in this version the variables are defined in the scope of the (synchronized) curly braces and can therefore not be accessed outside of the block. So, the question is: Is there some way to mark these curly braces as not defining a new scope block or marking the variables as belonging to the parent scope without having to declare them there?

(Note: I **do not** want to simply pull the `// Do something with version and content` into the synchronized block.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put ... no. Scoped variables are only available in the scope they are declared. Thats their whole point. This is described in section 14.4.2 of the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html#14.4.2):

> The scope of a local variable declaration in a block (§14.2) is the
>   rest of the block in which the declaration appears, starting with its
>   own initializer (§14.4) and including any further declarators to the
>   right in the local variable declaration statement.

Your  variables need to be declared in the scope they are to be used in (or higher, but definitely not lower).

Comment: And there is no way to increase the scope of a defined variable with some modifier either, right?

Comment: @MarkusA. - no, there is no modifier that will 'expose' a variable outside of the scope in which it was declared.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no.  It's just something that looks better/normal as you use the language more and more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want these variables not to be accessible from other scope, you may define both, the variables and the synchronized block in another scope.
Something like this:

```
{
    int    version;
    String content;
    synchronized (foo) {
        version = foo.getVersion();
        content = foo.getContent();
    }
    // Do something with version and content
}
```